# Entity Framework 4 not respecting database constraints for numeric fields

Tags: entity-framework-4

Say, I have a table in the DB defined as follows

Table: Foo
PkId - int, primary, autoincrement
Bar - int, allow null=false, no default

Now when generating the EF model from the database the 'Bar' field is correctly defined as Nullable=false, Type=Int32.

Now when I do the following

```
var foo = new Foo();  
context.AddToFoos(foo);  
context.SaveChanges();
```

The row is inserted into the database and 'Bar' has a value of 0? I would have expected an exception because Bar hasn't been set. I realise that 0 isn't null but its also not a value that I've set.

Is this by design or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not nullable and thus an int. The default of int is 0. So the DB is happy and the framework is fine as well.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but technically the value hasn't been set which is what the constraint is there for in the first place. Very strange.

Comment: That's a DB constraint. For .NET, the default of an Int32 is 0. That's why I said, the DB does not complain.

Comment: Thanks, so I might have to rephrase/repost my question. Do you know if what Im looking for is even possible in EF?

Comment: I think you can use T4 templates to do something like that, not nullable in DB, but nullable in EF.